# Where can I find the similar vocabulary structure information?

Tags: synonyms

For example, like 'possible' and 'impossible' have the same letters structure. Another scenario, when I met a new word, like 'fret', I want to know are there some similar words like that one?

Is there a search method or site can provide that kind of info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to peruse [printed thesauruses](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=thesaurus), or visit the many  thesauruses available on-line. One good example is [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com); another is [Roget's Thesaurus](http://www.roget.org).

Comment: Thesaurus.com is the treasure indeed. Thanks very much.